# Multidimensional array

Tags: code-golf

This is a **code-golf**, so keep your code small!

The **objective** is to create a function that receives 3 arguments:

- **Rows**(int): The max number of an item in each array;
- **Cols**(int): The max number of dimensions (sub-arrays);
- **Val**(*): The starting value in each item;

This function should return a **multidimensional array** with the proper size and with the items containing the value specified.

It should be able to return any number of dimensions.

#### Example:

```
var multiArray = createMultiArray(2, 4,'empty');

multiArray[0][0][0][0] === 'empty' //true
multiArray[0][0][0][1] === 'empty' //true
multiArray[0][0][0][2] === 'empty' //true
multiArray[0][0][1][0] === 'empty' //true
...
multiArray[2][2][2][2] === 'empty' //true
```

Comment: I'd recommend at the very least a different challenge type than a [tag:popularity-contest]. I'm having a tough time thinking what would make a recursive array initialization exercise popular. [tag:code-golf] would be better.

Comment: This feels homework-y, and even if I'm wrong it's not a particularly interesting challenge.

Comment: You guys gotta be kidding me ... If this was about [balls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550930/why-arent-my-ball-objects-shrinking-disappearing), [trolls](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23614/trolling-the-troll) or [dwarves](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25276/dwarves-and-coins) people would be interested ... what a shame. I'm gonna put my solution to this and try to find my faith in humanity again...

Comment: No reason to freak out. The point they are making is that this is quite a simple question which doesn't leave a lot of flexibility in the solutions (especially if you are prescribing recursive approachs), and hence it not very well suited for popularity contests. Also even if you leave it as a popularity contest, there is no incentive to keep the code small. So you may want to think about changing the winning criterion or lifting the recursion constraint to allow for creative approaches.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Please don't take it personally. Just look at these comments as recommendations for asking a better question, they are _not_ personal attacks. I see this is your first question attempt -- that makes you braver than I, and kudos for that, but there's no shame in taking the suggestions you have been giving, acting on them, and coming up with a better question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think a question on a different site is an indication of what would be received well here, and I can assure you that although some people may be interested in troll questions they attract a *lot* of negativity.

Comment: for the greater good I changed the contest type .. although i don't agree at all with you guys ... there are lots of ways to solve this ... and keeping the readability would make this much more informative ... well whatever ...

Comment: Meh, I was hoping you'd lift the recursion requirement. :D (then again "should" is not such a strong word)

Comment: "Informative" is subjective. If you want *useful, clearly written* ways to do things, a general QA site might be more appropriate than a puzzle site.

Comment: "Informative" is as subjective as "useful ... removed the recursive req ... still praying for those down votes to go away... god I hate this golfscript language .... whatever again

Comment: I also assume you have an off-by-one error in the number of items?

Comment: I just don't care anymore Howard ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### GolfScript

This is pretty trivial, so there's no need to over-complicate it:

```
{[1$({2$@(@A}{\;}if]*}:A;
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=e1sxJCh7MiRAKEBBfXtcO31pZl0qfTpBOwoKMiAzICdYJyBBIHA%3D)

Comment: @ProgramFOX, until they add syntax highlighting for GolfScript, I think it's best to leave it unhighlit. I don't know any other language with the same tokens.

Comment: @ProgramFOX You can even see in this short example that the `@` is coloured differently in two places as is the `A`.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Where is the byte count?

Comment: @Zacharý, when I wrote the answer it wasn't golf.

Answer (score 6):

#### GolfScript, 17 characters

A non-recursive approach in GolfScript.

```
{\{\[.;]*}+@*}:A;
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=e1x7XFsuO10qfStAKn06QTsKCjMgMiAnWCcgQSBw&run=true)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript, 132 characters

```javascript
function m(e,t,n){var r=0,i=[];var s=function(i){r++;for(var o=0;o<=e;o++){if(r==t)i[o]=n;else i[o]=s([])}r--;return i};return s(i)}
```

UnGolfed:

```javascript
function multiArray(maxRows, maxCols, val){
  var c = 0, farray = [];
  var recursive = function(array){
    c++;
    for(var r = 0; r <= maxRows; r++){ 
      if(c == maxCols) array[r] = val;
      else array[r] = recursive([]);
    }
    c--;
    return array;
  };
  return recursive(farray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 32 bytes

<s>Within reach of GolfScript for once!</s> Scrap that, I didn't see Howard's answer.

```
f=ConstantArray[#3,#+0Range@#2]&
```

Answer (score 0):

### APL, 19 bytes

```
{(¯1↑⍵)⍴⍨⊃(//)⌽2↑⍵}
```

Sample:

```
    {(¯1↑⍵)⍴⍨⊃(//)⌽2↑⍵} 2 4 'empty'
┌─────┬─────┐
│empty│empty│
├─────┼─────┤
│empty│empty│
└─────┴─────┘
┌─────┬─────┐
│empty│empty│
├─────┼─────┤
│empty│empty│
└─────┴─────┘

┌─────┬─────┐
│empty│empty│
├─────┼─────┤
│empty│empty│
└─────┴─────┘
┌─────┬─────┐
│empty│empty│
├─────┼─────┤
│empty│empty│
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Unneeded commute, you can change it to`{(⊃(//)⌽2↑⍵)⍴¯1↑⍵}`, and maybe even `{(⊃(//)⌽2↑⍵)⍴⊃⌽⍵}`

Comment: The commute is unneeded (and its absence would save us one character), but the second suggestion is wrong: "minus one take" returns a one element vector, whereas "first reverse" opens the box. [Try it online](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%28%u2283%28//%29%u233D2%u2191%u2375%29%u2374%u2283%u233D%u2375%7D%202%204%20%27empty%27&run).

Comment: Yeah, I don't do well with stuff like that in APL (which is probably bad).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 36 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,x:eval("["*b+"x"+"]*a"*b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bc6xCoQwEATQ/r4ibGPUFI5YCX6JWmxQQVARkcP7@pyVCBnYYhmG4U1NFxZd/aBGnXdXPX51sdJK5nO5JJc@0/tPg5rGTLZ0lUvGdT9/SfrZj3k7rbZF/xwJEYVgTURNsE2wTbBNRJtgTjAnmBPMCeYEc4I58XKGPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
$/@]$<@[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@59ma6Wi7xCrYuMQ/T81OSNfQT01t6CkUl0hTcFEwYgrtSKzRMHgPwA)